# Ways to track object changes

Tags: c++

I have class `MyClass` that can be modified by calling `setX`.
I want to know if an object of `MyClass` has been changed by calling `isChanged`.

In the code below, I don’t like to add `setDirty` or `m_dataChanged` in every method that can change the state of an object.

```cpp
class ChangesHolder
{
private:
  bool m_isChanged;
  // boost::signals2::signal<void()> m_dataChanged;
  // long m_stamps;

public:
  ChangesHolder()
    : m_isChanged{false}
    // , m_stamps{0}
  {
    // m_dataChanged.connect(std::bind(&ChangesHolder::setDirty, this));
  }

  bool isChanged() const
  {
    return m_isChanged;
    // return (m_stamps == 0);
  }

  void resetChanges()
  {
    m_isChanged = false;
    // m_stamps = 0;
  }

protected:
  void setDirty()
  {
    m_isChanged = true;
    // ++m_stamps;
  }
}

class MyClass : public ChangesHolder
{
private:
  int m_x;

public:
  void setX(int x)
  {
    if (m_x != x)
    {
      m_x = x;
      setDirty();
      // m_dataChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to register such methods like this:

```cpp
template<typename ... Funcs>
void startTrack(Funcs ... funcs)
{
  auto connect = [&](auto func)
  {
    // connect func to setDirty
  };
  do_foreach(connect, funcs ...);
}

MyClass::MyClass()
{
  startTrack(&MyClass::setX, &MyClass::setY);
}
```

How can this be done or maybe there are other ways to do it?

Comment: You *could* calculate a hash of all member variables (except the hash of course) in the constructor and store that. Then `isChanged` could re-calculate the hash and return `false` if the result is identical to the original value and `true` otherwise.

Comment: Personally, I would probably go with a simple `m_is_changed` bool that all non-`const` member functions would set to `true` (if they actually changed the object) though.